# Matplotlib threading; closing a specific figure instance

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-multithreading

The gist of the problem is:

I have a threadpool for generating images for machine learning training. I feed the pool with all images that have been annotated and I generate images from this. (it works)

I then add a visualisation step, i.e., generating nice images that are human understandable. For this I use matplotlib. (it works)

I then want to do this as an additional step in the pooling, and my code crashes. It seems like the issue is the close and clear statement:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[code for visualisation]
plt.savefig(f, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.cla()
plt.close()

plt.switch_backend(backend_org)
```

When one thread reaches the last lines all other `plt` crashes, therefore in Matlab one was able to specify a variable name that was operated on such that `close()` or other functions only executed on the specific image. I have not been able to find similar concept in matplotlib, but does it exist?

## Solution

Just to show the object oriented code.

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0,
                    wspace=0, hspace=0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.margins(0, 0)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())

label_viz = label2rgb(label, img, n_labels=len(label_names)) #generate labels
ax.imshow(label_viz)
ax.axis('off')

plt_handlers = []
plt_titles = []
for label_value, label_name in enumerate(label_names):
    [...]
    #generate legend

ax.legend(plt_handlers, plt_titles, loc='lower right', framealpha=.5)

f = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(f, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
#ax.cla() #resulting in crashes across the thread
plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: I'm not sure (its hard to tell without a [MCVE]), but I wonder if the answer is as simple as using the [OOA interface](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles): `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); <plotting code>; ax.cla(); plt.close(fig)`?

Comment: @tom I'll look into that now, a MVP would just be extremely big, but I may add it then.

Comment: The whole point of a minimal example is that it's not big!

Comment: @tom everybody knows, since I stated I may add it, infers that I of course would do something about the size. :)

Comment: Maybe [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037840/matplotlib-savefig-performance-saving-multiple-pngs-within-loop) is an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use the state based pyplot approach, but the object oriented version, where you work on an instance of `axes.Axes`. Otherwise different plots in different processes get mixed up. Short example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(...)
fig.savefig(...)
```