# how to distinguish axes between image, line plot and colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

N.B.: I have edited the question as it was probably unclear: I am looking for the best method to understand the type of plot in a given axis.

QUESTION:
I am trying to make a generic function which can arrange multiple figures as subplots.
As I loop over the subplots to set some properties (e.g. axis range) iterating over `fig.axes`, I need to understand which type every plot is in order to determine which properties I want to set for each of them (e.g. I want to set x range on images and line plots, but not on colorbar, otherwise my plot will explode).

My question is then how I can distinguish between different types.

I tried to play with try and except and select on the basis of different properties for different plot types, but they seem to be the same for all of them, so, at the moment, the best way I found is to check the content of each axis: in particular `ax.images` is a non empty list if a plot is an image, and `ax.lines` is not empty if it is a line plot, (and a colorbar has both empty).

This works for simple plots, but I wonder if this is still the best way and still working for more complex cases (e.g. insets, overlapped lines and images, subclasses)?

This is just an example to illustrate how the different type of plots can be accessed, with the following code creating three axes `l`, `i` and `cb` (respectively line, image, colorbar):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# create test figure
plt.figure()
b = np.arange(12).reshape([4,3])
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(b)
plt.colorbar()

# create  test objects
ax=plt.gca()
fig=plt.gcf()
l,i,cb = fig.axes

# do a simple test, images are different:
for o in l,i,cb: print(len(o.images))

# this also doesn't work in finding properties not in common between lines and colobars, gives empty list.
[a for a in dir(l) if a not in dir(cb)]
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: test image]

After creating the image above *in IPython*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(((0,1),(2,3)))
ax.scatter((0,1),(0,1), fc='w', ec='k')
ax.plot((0,1),(0,1))
fig.colorbar(ScalarMappable(), ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

I tried to investigate

```
In [48]: fig.axes
Out[48]: [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:label='<colorbar>'>]
```

I can recognize that one of the two axes is a colorbar — but it's easy to inspect the content of the individual axes

```
In [49]: fig.axes[0]._children
Out[49]: 
[<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fad9dda2b30>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7fad9dad04f0>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fad9dad09d0>]

In [50]: fig.axes[1]._children
Out[50]: 
[<matplotlib.patches.Polygon at 0x7fad9db525f0>,
 <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x7fad9db52830>,
 <matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x7fad9dad2320>]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting another answer. This is close, however `label='<colorbar>'` is the value given at initialization and can be changed with method `set_label`. 

After a quick search I wasn't able to understand what this property is for, as setting `label` at initialization sets the `ylabel` (the horizontal label, or title, is set with `title`). Maybe this can be used, together with the `len` to implement a logic which distinguish between the three types I have mentioned. I am not sure how safe this is!

Answer (score 0):

I have to remind you that

1. Matplotib provides you with many different container objects,
2. You can store the Axes destination in a list, or a dictionary, when you use it — you can even say `ax.ax_type = 'lineplot'`.

That said, e.g.,

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, plot
fig, ax = subplots()
plot((1, 2), (2, 1))
...
axes_types = []
for ax_i in fig.axes:
    try:
        ax_i.__getattr__('get_clabel')
        axes_types.append('colorbar')
    except AttributeError:
        axes_types.append('lineplot')
...
```

In other word, chose a method that is unique to each one of the differnt types you're testing and check if it's available.

Comment: Thanks, probably my question is not clear, I need to edit it. I see I can use the method here indicated to store which type of plot is contained in the axis, but I am more interested in knowing the best method to determine this type. 

I believe that adding properties at runtime is a generic feature of Python objects, and I understand it can be useful if the type of plot needs to be stored, but it is not needed if you need the information only once, or if you don't want to add undocumented properties of which other parts of code can be unaware.

Comment: @Vincenzooo I have also sketched a method to inspect an Axes and ascertain its _nature_.  Haven't you some comment in that respect?

Comment: @Vincenzooo I have posted another answer.

Comment: The example in this answer only tests the case of the line plot, while the try clause always fails because the axis don't have a `__getattr__` method neither a `get_clabel`. 

The idea of finding a unique method or property (together with a list of all possible types and their unique "identifying" properties) works in theory, and indeed was the basis of my question, but as I show in the last line of my example colorbars and lineplots seem to have all properties in common, so I failed in identifying any logic which could discriminate between the two.